# 3 column html template - content overflows though there is clear both and height is 100%

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs within a wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="leftbar">
Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet
</div><!--LEFTBAR-->

<div id="middle">
Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet
</div><!--middle-->

<div id="rightbar">
Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet
</div><!--RIGHTBAR-->

</div><!--wrapper-->
```

Both 'leftbar' and 'middle' are floating left, whilst 'rightbar' is floating right. 'wrapper' has `height:100%; clear:both;` set.

However, if there is a large amount of text or content in 'middle' it overflows the 'wrapper' div. I am struggling to figure out why this is occurring.

My CSS is:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    border: 2px solid #828fc4;
    clear:both;
}

#leftbar {
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 450px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#middle {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 580px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #2B308C;
    border-left: 1px dotted #2B308C;
}

#rightbar {
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 450px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you edited your question, I just came to know how it was overflowing, it is because you are using `height: 100%;`, so your div wont exceed the viewport, so use `height: auto;` instead and also use `overflow: auto;` for `#textcontent` instead of `clear: both;` as Musa told you to do..(Checked with firebug)

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#textcontent` and remove `height:100%` form `#textcontent` and `#maincontent`

Answer (score 1):

This is the css file with some minor additions:

- Text-align for your bar's
- Width in the wrapper was set to 1000px so all the px were distributed equally among the bar's.

> ```
> #wrapper {
> width: 1000px;
> height: auto;
> margin:auto;
> padding: 30px;
> margin-top: 40px;
> background-color:#FFF;
> color:#000;
> border: 2px solid #828fc4;
> clear:both;
> overflow:auto;
> }
> ```

```
#leftbar {
float:left;
width: 250px;
padding: 5px;
text-align:center;
}

#middle {
float:left;
width: 400px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
border-right: 1px dotted #2B308C;
border-left: 1px dotted #2B308C;
text-align: center;
}

#rightbar {
float:right;
width: 250px;
padding: 5px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Just my two cents

Answer (score 0):

If you need that for text only, try using CSS3 column.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow property and change height to auto.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    border: 2px solid #828fc4;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#middle {
    float:left;
    width: 580px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #2B308C;
    border-left: 1px dotted #2B308C;
}
```